# Event Listener for Multiple Radio Button Groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How would you have a dynamic Javascript/JQuery event listener to know which radio button group is clicked and retrieve the value of the checked element. For example if I have two radio button groups how would I know which one is clicked? How would I do it for a dynamic number of button groups?

Example of two radio button groups:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
     <input type="radio" name="input1" value="option1"/>
     <input type="radio" name="input1" value="option2"/>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
     <input type="radio" name="input2" value="option1"/>
     <input type="radio" name="input2" value="option2"/>
</div>
```

**Edit:** For anyone else wondering which of the following question below so far is "more" right, both are correct as `.change(function(e) {` is a shortcut for `.on('click', function(e) {`

**Edit 2:**Removed ID's

Comment: The event will give you access to the target, the radio button that raised the event, from there you can check its `name` to identify the group.

Comment: And just so you know, element `ID`s need to be _unique_ on any given `DOM` document.

Comment: Removed them as they were unnecessary, thank!

Comment: Note that `change` and `click` are not interchangeable events. Some elements won't fire a `change` event until they lose focus.

Comment: True in general scenarios they are not but in this case they are: `.change(function(e) {` and `.on('click', function(e) {` are interchangable. Also `.click` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This jquery will execute a callback that print in the console the name and the value of the 'clicked' (not changed) radio button.

```
$('input:radio').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.name); //e.currenTarget.name points to the property name of the 'clicked' target.
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value); //e.currenTarget.value points to the property value of the 'clicked' target.
});
```

try it:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbygxdbq/3/)

Answer (score 11):

To provide a pure JavaScript solution: create a collection for all your radio type inputs and then loop through them all adding an event listener to each. Using `this`, you can then access any attributes or properties you wish and, if necessary, the parent element as well.

```
var inputs=document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"),
    x=inputs.length;
while(x--)
    inputs[x].addEventListener("change",function(){
        console.log("Checked: "+this.checked);
        console.log("Name: "+this.name);
        console.log("Value: "+this.value);
        console.log("Parent: "+this.parent);
    },0);
```

Alternatively, as you mention that the number of groups is dynamic, you might need a live node list, which requires a little extra code to check the `input` `type`:

```
var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    x=inputs.length;
while(x--)
    if(inputs[x].type==="radio")
        inputs[x].addEventListener("change",function(){
            console.log("Checked: "+this.checked);
            console.log("Name: "+this.name);
            console.log("Value: "+this.value);
            console.log("Parent: "+this.parent);
        },0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Find the name of the input on the `change` event.

```js
$('input:radio').on('change', function(e){
  var name = e.currentTarget.name,
  value = e.currentTarget.value;
            
  $('.name').text(name);
  $('.value').text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
     <input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1" value="option1"/>
     <input type="radio" name="input1" id="input1" value="option2"/>
</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
     <input type="radio" name="input2" id="input2" value="option1"/>
     <input type="radio" name="input2" id="input2" value="option2"/>
</div>
<p>Name: <b class="name"></b></p>
<p>Value: <b class="value"></b></p>
```

Comment: This works also, just add the 'var' word before "wichOne" variable assignation in order to avoid the creation of a global variable. (can't edit the answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: For anyone else wondering which of the following question below so far is "more" right, both are correct as .change(function(e) { is a shortcut for .on('click', function(e) {

Yes, `.change(function(e) {` is a shortcut for `.on('click', function(e) {`, but when you are working with partial views for example in MVC, with `.change(function(e) {` the link or buttons in the page lose the hiperlink or don't work correctly, so you have to work with  `.on('click', function(e) {` where the hiperlink work fine.